# Need help replacing parts of json string with regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, json

How can I replace the following using Regex.Replace in my c# application?

Replace all of the following:

```
rendition\":{
```

with:

```
rendition\":[{
```

So i am adding the left square bracket.

and also

Replace:

```
\"}}
```

With:

```
\"}]}
```

I am using JsonConvert from NewtonSoft to convert XML to json. The rendition element in my xmls may or may not be an array. I am trying to force the converted json to an array

Comment: It might be more predictable to deserialize your XML to a c# object, then to serialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
(?<=rendition:)\"\{(.*?)\"\}\}
```

With:

```
\"[{$1\"}]}
```

In c#:

```
string json2 = Regex.Replace(json, "(?<=rendition\\\\\":)\\{(.*?)\\}\\}", "[{$1}]}");
```

See a [live demo](http://ideone.com/p9n6Ln) of this C# code running on ideone.

Comment: I have a c# application which converts xml using json converter..some xmls  have single elements whic I need to be an array of elements. So the examples that I have used are already converted json data

Comment: Thanks Bohemian but I am getting a bad compile constant error

Comment: That didnt work. here is the result after applying jsonData = Regex.Replace(jsonData, "(?<=rendition:\")\\{(.*?)\"\\}\\}", "[\\{\\1\"\\}]\\}"); Result = "{\"test1\":{\"is_live\":\"true\",\"type\":\"default\",\"rendition\":{\"@name\":\"test\",\"@url\":\"http://mytest\"}}}"

Comment: Are those literal backslashes in your string?

Comment: Yes they are generated by Newtonsoft json convert function

Comment: The end resut should be: "{\"test1\":{\"is_live\":\"true\",\"type\":\"default\",\"rendition\":[{\"@name\":\"test\",\"@url\":\"http://mytest\"}]}}"

Comment: OK. I got it sorted out. See edits plus a link to ideone showing the code working (as I now understand it). Cheers.